# geom_point and intervals between groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to increase intervals between groups when using geomp_points?

X is a categorical variable (Item) and each Item has 8 subjects (ID). In the plot, the interval between subjects is narrow.

```
ggplot(df5, aes(Item, TD)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL, group=ID),
    position = position_dodge(0.5), width = 0.5, size=0.3)+  
geom_point(aes(color = ID,fill=ID,shape = ID), position = position_dodge(0.5))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Spearman Correlation Coefficient (95%CI)", limits=c(-1, 1))+
  xlab("The Short Recovery Stress Scale Items")
```

Any commands to make the intervals larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is perhaps to control this by changing the image size. Compare

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(carb,mpg)) +
  geom_point()


ggsave('short.png',width = 2)

ggsave('long.png',width = 10)
```

[image]

[image]